# SpamAssassin Razor2 always gives confidence level above 50%

Tags: smtp, spamassassin, powermta

I have a powermta SMTP ready. Whenever I try to send HTML email, Razor2 gives me confidence above 50%.

I tried with different content, my IP is not blacklisted neither the domain. But Razor2 always gives me bad score, but if I send email with plain text and no html, then Razor2 check passes. I have all my headers properly set, I am using mail-tester.com to see the email score.

My question is how can I improve my email to get pass through Razor2. My email scores and header are on this link http://www.mail-tester.com/web-M5O2Ps

Comment: Your headers are looking fine, did you tried sending using different domain?

Comment: I haven't tried but if domain is causing the problem then why its working for non html emails?